# Regex pattern to capture numbers only

Tags: regex, regex-lookarounds

I need some help figuring out a regex pattern that will capture the 15-digits **highlighted** in each of the three examples below:

1. DASHES

> ASSESSMENT ROLL NO. 06043422 ABCDE INVESTMENTS INC 999 OAKDALE RD
> **19-08-01-3-400-01500**-0000-0 1 Total Due Date Jul 2, 2019 Tax Bill LEGAL DESCRIPTION > Billing Date PROPERTY LOCATION > ASSESSED OWNER

2. DOTS

> Abcde Real Estate (Ontario) Inc sale to 8888888 Ontario Inc
> Reduction of Taxes - Decision Roll Number **2629.040.017.00500**.0000
> 123 MAIN ST - closed 2019/08/02

3. NULL

> Assessed Value $854,750 $955,000 Issue Date: November 27, 2018
> PA_201811061688_r09_PAN-2.csv-29131-000000358 **19 04 044 340 02000** 0000
> A76FB ABCDE F282E 123 MAIN RD PLAN 329 BLK T PT LOT 22 CITY OF

Currently, I am using the following regex pattern with a **positive lookbehind**, followed by 15-digits with an optional non-digit between each one:

```
(?<=\D)([0-9]{1}\D?[0-9]{1}\D?[0-9]{1}\D?[0-9]{1}\D?[0-9]{1}[0-9]{1}\D?[0-9]{1}\D?[0-9]{1}\D?[0-9]{1}\D?[0-9]{1}[0-9]{1}\D?[0-9]{1}\D?[0-9]{1}\D?[0-9]{1}\D?[0-9]{1})
```

This pattern is not working because the **positive lookbehind** is matching the period in the currency immediately before the pattern and returning this false match:

> 87 19-08-01-1-300-015

Instead, I need a pattern that will return these three matches for the given examples:

**19-08-01-1-300-01500**

**2629.040.017.00500**

**19 04 044 340 02000**

Any suggestions on how to accomplish this?

Comment: Does `(?<!\S)\d(?:\D?\d){14}(?!\d)` work as expected? See https://regex101.com/r/0vPk3X/1

Comment: You can use: `\d(?:-?\d){14}`

Comment: Yes, @Wictor your pattern works perfectly.  Thank you.  I will explain a bit more in answer below.

Comment: Hi @Wictor, if you post your comment as an Answer, I will then be able to accept it as the answer.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The pattern given by @Wictor in the comment worked perfectly for me.

(?<!\S)\d(?:\D?\d){14}(?!\d)

It wasn't until I plugged this pattern into [RegExr.com](https://regexr.com/6t8mv) that I was able to fully understand it.

The ability to roll-over elements in the expression and have them explained to me was so helpful.  It made me realize that I need to consider using both **positive** and **negative** lookaheads and lookbehinds.  Until this solution offered by @Wictor, I had never fully grasped how to use a **negative lookahead**. Now that is has been explained to me, I think the answer is just brilliant.